# Anyone have an idea why a recently working connection to a SharePoint online list has stopped?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have tried adding a sharepoint onlist 2.0 beta link. It used to work, but recently I am getting the following error;

Expression.Error: The columns parameter must be null, specify the number of columns, specify a list of column names, or specify a table type.
Details:
[List]

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening, it is only happening on this one list on the site and all others work.

Thank you in advance